# Math.Pow C# negative number

Tags: c#, .net, excel

In Excel when I type in:

```
=-4^(1/3)
```

It gives me [image]

However when I do the same thing in C# it gives me Nan. How do I achieve the above in C#?

Comment: How did you do the same thing in C#? Can you show the code you wrote?

Comment: @Sweeper: Sure. Math.Pow(-4, 1/3.0)

Comment: You probably should have used `-Math.Pow(4, 1/3.0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Excel does is (-1)*(4^(1/3)). The NaN comes from the fact that the correct result is obviously a complex number, so you might want to look into C# complex type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `double x =-1*(double)Math.Pow(4, (double)(1.0/3)) ;` to get same results in csharp.